# c# SIMPLE factorial program

Tags: c#, factorial

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String UserNumber = this.textBox1.Text;
        int NewUserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(UserNumber);
        int result = 0;
        int second = 0;

        while (NewUserNumber >= 1) 
        {

            result = NewUserNumber * (NewUserNumber - 1);
            NewUserNumber--;
        }
        String i = Convert.ToString(result);
        this.textBox2.Text = i;
    }
}
```

While I understand this is homework for me, I am stuck. I really really don't want this solved, I want to do it myself.

I don't understand why it's not working.. It's outputting 2 no matter what I put in.

I could do this in Java easily but the converting gets to me..

Any help would be great.

Comment: Because you overwrite the contents of `result` each time.

Comment: Its just because you are intializing result with 0,,,initialize it with 1 as int Result=1.
And also you are overwriting value of result each time..Compute result as Result=result * (number-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not in the conversion. Please look at

```
result = NewUserNumber * (NewUserNumber - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            while (NewUserNumber > 1)
            {
                result = result * NewUserNumber;
                NewUserNumber--;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize result as

```
int Result=1;
```

And write for loop as follows

```
while (NewUserNumber >= 1) 
{
   result = result * NewUserNumber;
   NewUserNumber--;
}
```

OR

you can even use follwing

```
public int Factorial(int num)
{
  if(num==1)
     return 1;
  return num * Factorial(num-1);
}
```

Comment: OP did not want a solution, he wanted to know, why his solution didn't work.

Comment: What Corak said..Also, you don't initiate result with 1.

Comment: thanks.... still a little confused.. wouldn't result then = a much bigger number since you're storing the final result in it and then *ing it by the other number? (example of 5 is what i was thinking..)

Comment: Yes indeed. The way you written code will work fine till factorial of 5. There comes the need of recursive function. Using recursive function as i've mentioned , you need not to worry about it.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your while loop structure and how you are setting the result value outside it and the multiplication

```
    while (NewUserNumber >= 1) 
    {

        result = NewUserNumber * (NewUserNumber - 1);
        NewUserNumber--;
    }
    String i = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Also you have declared another `int second = 0;`  - dont see why you are declaring that.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try running over the code manually with different inputs.

You should run over the loop and try to figure what is the value of result and NewUserNumber  is in each iteration.

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run a debugger on your code then step through using the watch window.  This is easy to do and will show you exactly what each value is at each point (you set break points).  What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

int Factorial(int input)
{
    int answer = 0;

```
if (input > 0)
{
    count = 1;
    while (count <= input)
    {
        if (count == 1)
        {
            answer= 1;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            answer = count * answer;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only a positive integer.");
}

return answer;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number, fact;
        Console.WriteLine("enter the number for geting factorial");
        number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        fact = number;
        for (int i = fact - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(fact);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Did you see ` I really really don't want this solved, I want to do it myself.` and the accepted answer?