# Using a while loop in c# with a factorial

Tags: c#

I'm taking a intro to computer programming class at a community college and the instructor wants us to make a while look to display the factorial of the number 7. I wrote the code below as

```
using System;
namespace TheLoop
{
    class TheLoop
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 7;  
            long factorial = number;
            while (number > 1)
                factorial *= --number;
            System.Console.WriteLine(factorial);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

the code works fine. But the instructor wants us to display each step of the loop such as

```
1.  7 * 6 = 42
2.  42 * 5 = 210
3.  210 * 4 = 840
4.  840 * 3 = 2520
5.  2520 * 2 = 5040

and so on, other than just displaying the result
```

sorry I'm new to C# can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: Are you also new to programming in general?

Comment: Are you aware that you can have multiple statements in a `while` loop?

Comment: kind of sorry was that a bad question?

Comment: Try this sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966221/c-sharp-simple-factorial-program

Comment: Not really, I just want to determine where you are at, as just giving you the answer isn't likely to help. The non-negative answer on this post is close to what I would have posted; hopefully it helps!

Comment: buy this [book](http://www.amazon.com/5-0-Nutshell-The-Definitive-Reference/dp/1449320104)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about this:

```
int number = 7;  
int i = 1;
long factorial = number;
while (number > 1)
{
    factorial *= --number;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} * {2} = {3}", i++, factorial/number, number, factorial);
}
Console.WriteLine(factorial);
```

Comment: Congratulations, you are able to write the first task of `intro to computer programming class`

Comment: hey that worked great. I'm happy I could tackle most of this on my own. And I'm really happy it worked but ThePirate000 could you explain all that is going on the Console.WriteLine? I get the general idea that your imputing variables into a string. I was just a little confused on the math understanding part and what the varibales ment.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `while` you have access to both the current number and the current factorial, so something like this:

```
while (number > 1)
{
    // Print a Console.WriteLine() in here with what you want
    factorial *= --number;
}
```

Comment: haha ya was thinking that also, was just confused what I was suppost to put in Console.WriteLine() !!! :)

Comment: Try it, that's the best way to figure it out. :-)

Answer (score -5):

System.Console.WriteLine(number + " * " + --number + " = " + factorial);

Does this work?

Comment: No, it would not work. It does not have the step number or the running total.